# Somar linhas separadas de uma tabela filho com valores de uma tabela pai sem duplicar os valores da tabela pai

Tags: sql, sql-server

Existe uma tabela VENDA que gerou 2 registros na tabela DOCUMENTO

Eu precisava mostrar a soma total de campos de valores dessas duas linhas (mostrando linha a linha), porém elas precisam somar com alguns campos de valores da tabela VENDA sem "duplicar"..

TABELA VENDA => ID = 1, OUTROVALOR = 5
TABELA DOCUMENTOS: 
 ID 1, TARIFA = 15, TAXA = 5
ID 2, TARIFA = 8, TAXA = 2

```
SELECT DOCUMENTO.ID, (SUM(DOCUMENTO.TARIFA) + SUM(DOCUMENTO.TAXA) + SUM(VENDA.OUTROVALOR)) AS VALORTOTAL
FROM VENDAS VENDA
JOIN DOCUMENTOS DOCUMENTO ON (DOCUMENTO.VENDA = VENDA.ID)
WHERE VENDA.ID = 1
GROUP BY DOCUMENTO.ID
```

Resultado:

Linha 1 => ID = 1,  VALORTOTAL = 25.
Linha 2 => ID = 2, VALORTOTAL = 15.
Ou seja, o campo OUTROVALOR da tabela VENDA foi somado tanto na primeira linha quanto na segunda linha
Então a minha dúvida é: Como eu poderia fazer para somar o campo OUTROVALOR em apenas uma das 2 linhas?
Resultado esperado:

Linha 1 => ID = 1,  VALORTOTAL = 25. (Somou os 5 reais do campo OUTROVALOR 1x)
Linha 2 => ID = 2, VALORTOTAL = 10.  (Não deve somar os 5 reais novamente. )

EDIT: Eu também aceito somar 2,50 em cada linha, se for mais fácil

Comment: Você confirma que o resultado de sua query exibiu a linha `Linha 2 => ID = 2, VALORTOTAL = 15.`? Mesmo com `... ON (DOCUMENTO.VENDA = VENDA.ID) WHERE VENDA.ID = 1`?

Comment: Sim, pois tanto o ID 1 e o ID 2 da tabela DOCUMENTOS possuem o campo VENDA = 1 (id), no caso a tabela DOCUMENTOS é uma tabela filha de VENDAS e a venda gerou 2 DOCUMENTOS

Answer (score 1):

Thiago, segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando o operador *Apply* para fazer a contagem de documentos da venda, e com essa contagem fazer a divisão do valor entre os documentos:

```
select ca.Id, ca.Tarifa + ca.Taxa + v.OutroValor / QtdeDocs as ValorTotal
from Venda as v
cross apply
(
  select d.Id, d.Tarifa, d.Taxa, count(1) over() as QtdeDocs
  from Documentos as d
  where d.Venda = v.Id
) as ca
where v.Id = 1
```

Espero que ajude